# Did Heimdall sacrifice himself for Hulk?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

Firstly, it's not wrong to say that in *Avengers: Infinity War* Thanos and Black order may know how to bypass Heimdall's senses, provided that planetary-level Joutens can do it and even Dark elves INCLUDING their ships, so why not UNIVERSAL-level Thanos, his black order and his ship.

Secondly, Heimdall **saw Thanos coming**, and saw his resources like wielding a stone with space for more, and his black order.

Fearing for Thor and Hulk (fight with Thanos), Thanos may have killed Hulk on the spot, so he decides to transport Hulk to Earth knowing it will be for **one last time** knowing the consequences as he judged Hulk's life is more valuable.

So in both cases, Hulk's beating was inevitable, so did  Heimdall sacrifice himself for Hulk?

Comment: In your last statement "So in both cases, Hulk's beating was inevitable", which is the 2nd case of Hulk getting beaten up?

Comment: @KharoBangdo In both cases I meant whether Heimdall would have seen Thanos coming or not, their fate was inevitble,thats what I meant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Heimdall sacrifice himself?

### In a sense...but he's doomed anyway.

> ... for the Hulk

**Not directly.**

From the action, it's clear that the Black Order is killing the wounded *anyway* so Heimdall is doomed regardless, especially since the ship is destroyed afterwards.

What he is clearly doing is sending *information* back to Earth the quickest and simplest way possible... by sending someone who was there and can tell the story of Thanos and his intentions.

His only other choices would seem to be Thor (who is imprisoned in metal) so it's not clear even if he *could* send Thor in that condition, and Loki...and he knows that Loki is untrustworthy.

So he sends the Hulk...or rather Hulk/Banner directly to Dr Strange.

Comment: IMO he chose Hulk/Banner maybe he has a high IQ (as Banner), and both hulk and banner is trusted by every members in avengers, and he can explain better about coming threat