# Why didn't Heimdall save Thor instead of Hulk?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war

In **Avengers: Infinity War** Heimdall sends Hulk to earth. Hulk was beaten badly by Thanos. And I don't think Heimdall didn't know Hulk much. Why didn't he save Thor by sending him to Earth?

He is Heimdall's rightful king and an Asgardian. So why didn't he save Thor instead of Hulk?

Comment: Related if not dupe = https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/93438/did-heimdall-sacrifice-himself-for-hulk

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because that was an easy choice, Ebony Maw captured Thor already:

[image]

and Thanos was also looking at Thor too and Heimdall didn't have multiple chances, as he said:

> Allfathers...let the dark magic flow through me one **last**...time.
>   - [Source](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=avengers-infinity-war)

So he picked the easy option of Hulk as he was not captured in metal scrap and was lying on the floor nearer to him than Thor:

[image]

Comment: Adding something here, Bruce Banner is one of smartest dudes in the MCU, maybe Heimdall thought he would be much better to explain the coming threat to his fellow Avengers, Heimdall may've been known that Banner is trusted by all Avengers, and wasn't part of Civil War, so he's good with everybody. And since he's a smart guy, he may help to create better battle plan for coming threat (that one is a stretch, since Thor have better battle experiences than both Banner+Hulk and better understanding on aliens)

Comment: @Ankit Sharma Why did Heimdell say dark magic?

Comment: @AsifIqubal that's what they used to send Thor in Avengers too https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/93873/1190

Comment: @Vishwa no need to think that much, chill

Comment: @masterArSuKa That's the way I'm programmed with ;)

Comment: las time I check A person held by metal bars would not have any prob being transferred by BIFROST , also as the protector of the REALM gates , Heimdall should be more concerned about saving the last prince of Asgard rather than just another being